# Dojo Spider Chart Change Colors

Tags: charts, dojo, web-crawler, dojox.charting

Hi I want to change the colors of series in Spider Chart for Dojo Library?

Currently I dont know from where the default colors for the chart is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colors are coming from the chart theme. You can set a different theme on the chart doing something like the following:

```
myChart.setTheme(myAlternateTheme).render();
```

You can find predefined themes in the themes folder.

If you want to create your own we your own theme to with let's say blue, white and red colors you can do as follows:

```
myChart.setTheme(new SimpleTheme(["#0000ff", "#ffffff", "#ff0000"])).render();
```